# Integration of two gaussian functions from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Tags: probability, integration, gaussian-integral

We need to integrate $z$ from $- \infty$ to $\infty$ where we are given the below equation:

$$a \int  \exp \left\{ \frac{-(z-m)^2}{2 \sigma_{m}^2}\right\}\exp \left\{ \frac{-(y-z)^2}{2 \sigma_{i}^2}\right\} dz$$

The resulting function will also be a Gaussian. I would appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: Why those ugly braces? Integrate $w$ with respect to what? Can you please replace all those irrelevant constants like $$\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_m},\,\frac1{2({\sigma_m}^2+{\sigma_i}^2)}$$ with letters from the beginning of Latin alphabet like $a,\,b,\,\dotsc$? That will clean up the mess and show you do really want others to help with the exact issue you are struggling with, which is not really clear from your post.

Comment: If the integral is *definite* and you integrate with respect to $z$, then you cannot have $z$ in the result.

Comment: The answer cannot be the result of the integral. It is probably a rewrite of the integrand.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the book where this example is given. I cant understand, how the author derived the equation (4.51) from equation: (4.44), (4.49) and (4.50).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{(x-a)^2}{A} + \frac{(x-b)^2}{B} = \frac{1}{AB}\left((A+B)x^2 - 2(aB + bA)x + a^2B + b^2A\right)$$

Can you complete the square?

Comment: thanks for the hint. I have already wrote that step. but I cant go anywhere after that! :(

Comment: @jhon_wick, once you complete the square you end up with a Guassian function with an additional constant